# Delete array child where value = somevalue in multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimentional array like this `$membergroups` :

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [id] => 1645819602 
        [name] => Oryza NurFa 
        [first_name] => Oryza 
        [last_name] => NurFa 
        [work] => MAN 2 Yogyakarta ) 
    [1] => 
    Array ( [id] => 100000251643877 
        [name] => Lathif Pambudi 
        [first_name] => Muhammad Lathif 
        [last_name] => Pambudi 
        [work] => Omah TI ) 
    [2] => 
    Array ( [id] => 1152078197 
        [name] => Novantio Bangun 
        [first_name] => Novantio 
        [last_name] => Bangun 
        [work] => Pertamina))
```

How to delete one of child array with specific value. For the example, I want to delete an array with `[id] => 100000251643877` inside? So the output will be :

```
Array ( [0] => 
        Array ( [id] => 1645819602 
            [name] => Oryza NurFa 
            [first_name] => Oryza 
            [last_name] => NurFa 
            [work] => MAN 2 Yogyakarta ) 
        [1] => 
        Array ( [id] => 1152078197 
            [name] => Novantio Bangun 
            [first_name] => Novantio 
            [last_name] => Bangun 
            [work] => Pertamina))
```

Here is my php code, but it doesn't work :

```
if (($key = array_search($user_fbid, $membergroups)) !== false) {
   unset($membergroups[$key]);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a foreach you can do the job like this

```
$id = 100000251643877;//Example
foreach($membergroups as $key => $value){
  if($value['id'] == $id){
    unset($membergroups[$key]);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the array successfully deleted. But after it was removed, the index of another array doesn't change. With your code, before : [1] [2] [3] [4],, after : [1] [3] [4].. How to keep the index remained sequentially?

Comment: You need to sort the array..Use `ksort($array);`

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `array_column` but only for `php >= 5.5`

```
if (($key = array_search($user_fbid, array_column( $membergroups, 'id') ) !== false) {
   unset($membergroups[$key]);
}
```

`array_column( $membergroups, 'id')` search in membergroup multidimensional array for id column, and return tou you an array containing all rows values entries with id key.

array_column -> [**`MANUAL`**](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-column.php)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the whole array:

```
foreach ($membergroups as $idx => $group) {
  if ($group['id'] === $user_fbid) {
    unset($membergrouops[$idx]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($membergroups as $key => $value){
  if($value['id'] == $user_fbid){
   unset($membergroups[$key]);  
  }
}
```

Don't forget to merge the array after removing key to keep the index sequantially

```
$membergroups = array_merge($membergroups);
```